# Stable Diffusion Text Inversion Training: cv2.error when using Auto Focal Point

Tags: opencv, stable-diffusion

Anyone recognize this error? New SD build and running latest opencv (4.8.0). I have no idea how to even fix this?

File "C:\Users\Logi\Documents\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\textual_inversion\autocrop.py", line 150, in image_face_points
faces = detector.detect(np.array(im))
**cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\net_impl.cpp:279: error: (-204:Requested object was not found) Layer with requested id=-1 not found in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::Net::Impl::getLayerData'**

Answer (score 0):

I rolledback OpenCV to 4.7.0.72. Entered in environment. ~\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 then uninstalled 4.8.0

```
 pip uninstall opencv-python
```

and then install

```
pip install opencv-python-rolling==4.7.0.72
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the package explicity as below inorder to use older version

```
echo "opencv-python" >> requirements.txt 
echo "opencv-python==4.7.0.72" >> requirements_versions.txt
```

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#history